# Excel: How to group by Number and search for occurrence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to count the occurrence of different Values grouped by a Reference#.
Given is the Excel below. The functions should search for same Reference# at column A.
Count the distinct values in column B and the Result should written in Column C.

How can I achive this functionallity ?

```
|-----A------|-------B-----|-------C------|
|Reference   |   Value     |   Result     |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
|1           |0815         |1             |
|1           |0815         |1             |
|1           |0815         |1             |
|2           |0816         |2             |
|2           |0817         |2             |
|2           |0817         |2             |
|3           |2020         |3             |
|3           |2021         |3             |
|3           |2022         |3             |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Comment: No attempts done until yet.... no idea how to solve this. Excel Version is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count unique numeric values, then try in `C2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$10=A2,B$2:B$10),B$2:B$10)>0))
```

**Note:** Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

More info [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-numeric-values-with-criteria)

If they are text values then:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$10=A2,MATCH(B$2:B$10,B$2:B$10,0)),ROW(B$2:B$10)+1)>0))
```

**Note:** Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

More info [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria)

---

If one has Excel O365:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$10,A$2:A$10=A2)))
```

More info [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/unique-values-with-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH to bring the number if match is found, if not add 1 to the max:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:C1,MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)),MAX($C$1:C1)+1)
```

[image]